# SpeechClient not importing in intellij

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying this: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java

But the import `import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechClient;` shows error. Rest of the classes under the cloud speech api are importing just fine.

I have created the GCP Service account and downloaded the json file for my project, and I even set my google credential to that json file using powershell.

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognitionAudio;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognitionConfig;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognizeResponse;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechClient;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechRecognitionAlternative;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechRecognitionResult;
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;

public class QuickstartSample {

  /**
   * Demonstrates using the Speech API to transcribe an audio file.
   */
  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    // Instantiates a client
    try (SpeechClient speechClient = SpeechClient.create()) {
      // The path to the audio file to transcribe
      String fileName = "./resources/audio.raw";

      // Reads the audio file into memory
      Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
      byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
      ByteString audioBytes = ByteString.copyFrom(data);

      // Builds the sync recognize request
      RecognitionConfig config = RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
          .setEncoding(AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)
          .setSampleRateHertz(16000)
          .setLanguageCode("en-US")
          .build();
      RecognitionAudio audio = RecognitionAudio.newBuilder()
          .setContent(audioBytes)
          .build();

      // Performs speech recognition on the audio file
      RecognizeResponse response = speechClient.recognize(config, audio);
      List<SpeechRecognitionResult> results = response.getResultsList();

      for (SpeechRecognitionResult result : results) {
        // There can be several alternative transcripts for a given chunk of speech. Just use the
        // first (most likely) one here.
        SpeechRecognitionAlternative alternative = result.getAlternativesList().get(0);
        System.out.printf("Transcription: %s%n", alternative.getTranscript());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What error does it show, exactly?

Comment: It's basically saying that the particular class is not found

Comment: It's best to copy and paste the exact error message.